# How to receive line level audio signal from a notebook jack port?

Tags: drivers, audio, jack, pipewire

As a follow up to my [reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxaudio/comments/1949nwr/how_to_use_my_notebooks_jack_port_as_input_port/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) I'd like to ask:

How to receive audio from a jack port, if the signal is line level, but the driver processes it like if it was mic level (because this a casual notebook jack port)?

I've plugged my synthesizer to a notebook jack port and it shows up as complete noise (works with speakers). I suspect it might be because, in the notebook this port would usually be used for a microphone, maybe together with headphones?

It might be that the driver processes the jack signal wrong (say, mismatches base line with signal line, idk about jacks) or that it amplifies greatly a signal it expects to be much lower, expecting mic level, gotting line level.

How do I inspect these things? How do I modify it? How do I even find a driver responsible? Is my hypotheses possible?

I include portion of `lshw` printout I guess is relevant to the sound driver and video driver:

```
        *-multimedia
             description: PCH
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             logical name: card0
             logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D2
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:131 memory:b4528000-b452bfff memory:b4510000-b451ffff
           *-input:0
                product: HDA Intel PCH Mic
                physical id: 0
                logical name: input27
                logical name: /dev/input/event16
           *-input:1
                product: HDA Intel PCH Headphone
                physical id: 1
                logical name: input28
                logical name: /dev/input/event17
```

THanks!!!